# Extract data from a text file with grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression, tcsh

I have the following line in a text file:

```
severity: Error , count: 10 violations , waived: 7, not waived: 3
```

How can extract the number after `not waived:` (i.e. `3`) using a single `grep` command in a `tcsh` shell?

Comment: `grep` is the command to print the lines that match a pattern. That's what `grep` (`g/re/p`) stands for. Only some `grep` implementations (like `pcregrep` or GNU `grep`) have provision to print _parts_ of the matching lines as an extension. What system are you on? More generally, what you're asking for is more a job for `awk` or `sed`.

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier with `awk` in this case:

```
% awk '{ print $NF }' file.txt
3
```

`$NF` is the data in the last whitespace-delimited field (column) in the input record (line).

`grep` is *generally* used to get whole lines matching a particular pattern, but some implementations may be used to get bits of lines as well, using the `-o` flag (will return only the bits that are matched):

```
% grep -o '[[:digit:]]$' file.txt
3
```

But for general processing of data on lines, I'd recommend `awk` over `grep`.

If the file contains other lines of less relevant data:

```
% awk '/^severity:/ { print $NF }' file.txt
```

If, additionally, the field is not at the extreme end of the line, you may want to use `sed`:

```
% sed -n '/^severity:/s/^.*not waived: \([[:digit:]]*\).*$/\1/p' file.txt
3
```

Comment: this is working for me now   grep "severity" ace_sc.log | awk '{print $NF}'  but what if in some other case something else is coming after not waived: 3

Comment: @vishnuvarkala To combine the two into one `awk`:  `awk '/severity/ { print $NF }' file.txt`.

Comment: how can I capture the number coming after "not waived:" instead of getting the  last whitespace-delimited field. something similar to this in perl not\swaived\:\s(\d+)

Comment: @vishnuvarkala Updated my answer again.

Comment: @vishnu, if you know `perl`, why not use it: `perl -lne 'print $1 if /\bnot waived:\s*(\d+)/' < file`